# Spring Session Management Issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, spring-transactions

I am using Hibernate+Spring+Jsf in my demo application i will want Spring will handel transaction management So i made these entries in application-context.xml file..

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Beans Declaration -->
        <bean id="User" class="com.otv.model.User"/>

        <!-- User Service Declaration -->
        <bean id="UserService" class="com.otv.user.service.UserService">
            <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" />
        </bean>

        <!-- User DAO Declaration -->
        <bean id="UserDAO" class="com.otv.user.dao.UserDAO">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
        <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />   
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />   
            <property name="user" value="postgres" />   
            <property name="password" value="hariom" /> 
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
            <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" /> 
        </bean>

        <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
        <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.otv.model.User</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

        <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
        <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
           <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

And UserService.java class

```
package com.otv.user.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.otv.model.User;
import com.otv.user.dao.IUserDAO;

/**
 * 
 * User Service
 * 
 * @author onlinetechvision.com
 * @since 25 Mar 2012
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    // UserDAO is injected...
    IUserDAO userDAO;

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().addUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Delete User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().deleteUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Update User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        getUserDAO().updateUser(user);
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     * 
     * @param  int User Id
     */
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        return getUserDAO().getUserById(id);
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     */
    public List<User> getUsers() {  
        return getUserDAO().getUsers();
    }

    /**
     * Get User DAO
     * 
     * @return IUserDAO - User DAO
     */
    public IUserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    /**
     * Set User DAO
     * 
     * @param IUserDAO - User DAO
     */
    public void setUserDAO(IUserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

}
```

Now i my bean i am doing

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{UserService}")
    IUserService userService;

     */
    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Service
     * 
     * @param IUserService - User Service
     */
    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public String addUser() {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(getId());
            user.setName(getName());
            user.setSurname(getSurname());
            userService = getUserService();
            userService.addUser(user);
            userService.deleteUser(null);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return ERROR;
    }
```

Here in this code `userService.deleteUser(null);`
 I am forcefully throughing exception but still data saved in database ? Why not Trasaction management handle this situation if exception coming why it is not rollback the data?

**UserDAO Class**

```
package com.otv.user.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.otv.model.User;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * Get Hibernate Session Factory
     * 
     * @return SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
     */
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Set Hibernate Session Factory
     * 
     * @param SessionFactory - Hibernate Session Factory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    /**
     * Delete User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }

    /**
     * Update User
     * 
     * @param  User user
     */
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(user);
    }

    /**
     * Get User
     * 
     * @param  int User Id
     * @return User 
     */
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                                            .createQuery("from User where id=?")
                                            .setParameter(0, id).list();
        return (User)list.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     * @return List - User list
     */
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the transaction boundaries are each method on the UserService class. When you say `userService.addUser(user)` that's one transaction started and finished. Hence when you say `userService.deleteUser(null)` it's another transaction -- and although it fails, the previous one is not rolled back because it's already comitted.

If you want to do everything in one single transaction, annotate your addUser() with @Transactional (or enclose in programmatic transaction)

Comment: What do you mean programmatic transaction?

Comment: Declarative transaction boundary is when you annotate your method with @Transactional. Programmatic transaction boundary is when you call something like `session.beginTransaction()`. I was referring to `public String addUser()` on your last code snippet which does not have @Transactional annotation

Comment: yes i removed and added at class level only but now even i am not forcefully throwhing exception but now data is not saved in DB

Comment: What persistence technology are you using. If you're using JPA/Hibernate make sure you flush at the end so the changes are propagated.

Comment: I am using Hibernate and where i have to add FLush? And i haved added my DAO class in question

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation on the method defines the boundary of the transaction (unless someone else already has an "outer Transaction" running). In the same way the `@Transactional` annotation of the class makes all *single* calls to (public) methods of instances of that class transactional, but does **not** make *consecutive* methods calls to the same instance being wrapped up in a single transaction. Instead every single method call runs in its own transaction and the transaction is committed if the method returns normally. (By default it even gets committed if a checked Exception is thrown though you can change this with the `rollbackFor` and `noRollbackFor` parameters.)

So in your case you have two transactions; one for this call:

```
userService.addUser(user);
```

which successfully creates a user and is committed when the call to `addUser` is finished, and a second one:

```
userService.deleteUser(null);
```

which is rolled back when the NullPointerException raises out of the method call. (I guess you get an NPE here, and as this is a subclass of RuntimeExcepotion, it causes a rollback.)

If you want to have both statements in a single transaction you need to have the transaction on a higher level. The '@Transactional` annotations here will not hurt, but they do not what you want.

Comment: `@Transactional` is only a shorthand to make all public methods of that class transactional. It dies not make "the whole class" transactional.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we use trasaction management so that if exception comes its roolback the data

Comment: Well, for example in your case you could mark the `addUser()` method on the class *containing* the `IUserService userService` as `@Transactional` and then that should roll back the transaction when the exception propagates outside the `addUser()` method - assuming that it got called form another class when it got injected via spring as an interface. Do not catch `DataAccessException` on the `addUser()` class but the one calling it, however.